# Paper Suggestion/Recommendation Tools

Tags: literature-search

To make literature search simpler and more efficient, I'm looking for a good tool that would come up with a list of publications based on a given set of publications/research areas. So far, I've found [Mendeley Suggest](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/web/05-mendeley-suggest) but it does not seem to work all that well. I was wondering if someone in this community might know about a better tool or an altogether better approach for pursuing efficient literature search.

Comment: Hmmm. The one we used to use was called a _Library_. If a tool is too specialized it will come with an assumed set of both false positives and false negatives. The latter is more problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The low-tech way will be to check in google scholar who cites each of your papers. You list will be ranked by citations number, so you can immediately see which paper is more important.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question about how to _find_ papers.

Comment: This approach would simply find papers that cite a reference paper. I'm looking for other papers that are related to the reference paper, perhaps published even earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The old school way would simply to read a review article on the research topic or field, that is what they are there for - to provide efficient access to recent literature! Note that using Google Scholar combined with a good review article can help you search both forward and backward in time. The review article itself summarizes the past literature. If the review was published some years ago, the citations to that article on Scholar will help you quickly and efficiently learn the recent progress.

A related minor suggestion is that I also find that investing some time building a profile on a site such as ResearchGate can pay dividends, as it will show you recent papers by authors you follow, and also help surface papers you might be interested in. However, this is a longer-term strategy for keeping abreast of the literature.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was hoping that there are some standard machine learning tools out there that can help classify papers, and possibly save me the work of manually searching for the papers :D